# How to recycle application pool in c# .net 2.0 within application code not from another application?

Tags: c#, .net

How to recycle web application pool in c# .net 2.0 within application code not from another application? I have tried code that works fine if run from another solution/programe but fails when executes from the application whose pool I need to recycle?

[image]

Comment: Yes, code that tries to commit suicide often fails as a result, even if it is successful. *Especially* if it is successful.

Comment: but this code is working fine if runs from another solution?

Comment: Is this the Depressed Phoenix pattern?

Comment: @Osama, that's logical. If it runs outside of the app pool, then it is committing murder, not suicide.

Comment: is is possible to recycle application pool programaticaly within application @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: @Osama, that would not be a good idea and looks a lot like an X-Y problem. Why do you want to recycle the app pool in the first place? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: it is a requirement that their should be a screen in our web application that  is able to recycle application pool and restart some windows services deployed on webserver?

Comment: weird requirement, recycling the application pool is an administrative task which has nothing to do in your application. But if you really want to achieve that behavior you can invoke another process in charge of killing your using Process.Start. But you should really consider Frédéric comment and discuss with the people writing such requirements to understand the use case and find a better approach.

Comment: How about `HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();`

Comment: @RJM 'HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();' does not perform pool recycle of application.